# Is it possible to recover wannacry encrypted files through file system recovery?

Tags: windows, ransomware, data-recovery, recovery, wannacry

As I saw wannacry encrypts files and then removes them, I thought it is possible to recover some of the original files by file system recovery using a bootable OS.

Is it possible to use a bootable recovery OS to recover wannacry encrypted files?

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Half of this post is a request to do some work for you. What's remaining is a question: "is it possible" the answer is "it depends", on a lot of factors.

Comment: @techraf If you are sure about the dependencies I would glad to give you the right answer. but please consider the real behavior of Wannacry not just guessing.

Comment: No, I think you misread my comment. I did not try to answer, I explained why I think this question should be closed. Which I already voted for.

Comment: @techraf As there is no documentation for viruses you can't be sure of the behavior without testing it. As you can see at the answer bellow, I wanted to be sure if the idea works or not. What else can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tested in [here](https://youtu.be/ounNoeQ4Vd4?t=11m49s):

- Wannacry overwrites your data.
- You cannot use recovery applications.

No matter if you have lots of free storage.

File history probably won't work too.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **no**. 
There is [some analysis on ransomwaree](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121080/do-the-most-common-ransomware-programs-delete-the-original-files-as-they-go-or) back then. Ransomware indeed think ahead of undelete tools.

Perhaps you mistaken it with system run under virtual machine (e.g. VM snapshot)  ; intrusion monitoring system (that also take snapshot of the machine state or files from time to time, like tripwire, OSSEC); version control system, etc.

Comment: Just read about file history and video linked in my answer,  I saw lots of viruses that won't overwrite original file and just remove them. But this thing is more advanced.