# How to stop cryptolocker attacks?

Tags: ransomware

There are many crypto viruses being launched and this crypto virus is very painful for any system. All your data, songs, movies, pictures, and many other docs and project files are encrypted.

How to stop it? And what we can do to secure our data?

Comment: Also see [What should you do if you catch encryption ransomware mid-operation?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/what-should-you-do-if-you-catch-encryption-ransomware-mid-operation) and [How does ransomware get on people's computers?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120325/how-does-ransomware-get-on-peoples-computers).

Comment: Regular backup that the virus can't overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I've only dealt with this kind of virus in one instance, but in that experience, there was nothing I could do. I couldn't break the encryption, couldn't remove the virus, couldn't do anything. The guidance I got was to (in the future) back everything up and if it happens again to unplug and wipe that device, then restore from my last good backup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Malwarebytes software against these Ransomware. It's free to download and has a very quick setup.

[Link](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/malwarebytes-news/2016/01/introducing-the-malwarebytes-anti-ransomware-beta/)

It´s now in his Beta version but on my systems, it´s running quite good.

Comment: It is useful to note that it only works against certain types of ransomware.

Comment: True, but against most common Ransomware it´s working properly